Testing Cross-Origin-Resource-Policy (CORP) with an iframe - not working as expected
I'm trying to test the Cross-Origin-Resource-Policy (CORP) header to ensure it's functioning as expected on my site. I've configured the Cross-Origin-Resource-Policy header with the value same-origin on my server (e.g., mysite.co.in). The goal is to verify that content from my site cannot be embedded on a different domain.
Set CORP Header on My Site - I applied the header Cross-Origin-Resource-Policy: same-origin on mysite.co.in.
Tested Embedding from a Different Domain - created a simple HTML page on a different domain like on codepen with the following code:
<iframe src="https://mysite.co.in" width="1500" height="600" style="border: none;" title="Testing CORP"></iframe>

Expected Outcome:
The iframe should not load, and I should see an error in the browser console or network tab indicating that the content was blocked due to CORP.
Actual Outcome: The site is working fine on codepen's iframe

I don't think this applies to documents loaded in iframes, only to resources loaded by elements such as img, audio, video, script. You should speficy frame-ancestors via your CSP instead, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/frame-ancestors

Or you can use X-FRAME-OPTIONS an set it to DENY or SAMEORIGIN if you want to prevent external sources from showing your site in an iframe

You should set Response header `X-Frame-Options to "SAMEORIGIN" for your web page.
Check : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options

@OshanAbeykoon I am using both CSP and X-FRAME-OPTIONS, and they are working well. The idea is to have an extra layer of security. Is it advisable to use both, or can we rely solely on CSP?

@C3roe I am using both CSP and X-FRAME-OPTIONS, and they are working well. The idea is to have an extra layer of security. Is it advisable to use both, or can we rely solely on CSP?

I tried all these three but they did not working as expected. Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy (COOP) ,Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy (COEP),Cross-Origin-Resource-Policy (CORP)

@KaramjeetSingh, Did you check your response headers in the code pens network request? Does it get sent correctly?

@OshanAbeykoon yes, This is what it shows: https://app.screencast.com/t6cgkvyZMbyXr

"I tried all these three but they did not working as expected" - that's cause your expectations are wrong. That CORP doesn't apply here, I already mentioned right at the start. COOP applies to top-level documents only (which an [i]framed document is not), COEP works in the other direction (documents from which sources, is your document allowed to embed.)

My question is, Is there any need if am using both CSP and X-FRAME-OPTIONS to use these three. Still worthfull to use it or not? Thanks in advance!
